# Forgetting / unsetting passwords for TrueVFS

Tags: java, encryption, passwords, truevfs

I'm writing a program that uses different TrueVFS' encrypted archives for each of its users. That means user A starts the program and after she's finished she does not terminate the program but just logs off (while the program still is running).
After that user B continues to use the program (after logging in) and should only have access to his individual TrueVFS encrypted archive.

The point here is: How can my program forget resp. unset passwords that were previously used to access a TrueVFS encrypted archive without terminating the program altogether?

Even with help from the author I wasn't able to achieve this. It is probably a stupid mistake I made but I can't figure it out, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's a link to the mailing list where I first asked this question:

https://java.net/projects/truezip/lists/users/archive/2013-09/

Here's a working and ready to run code sample that demonstrates the perceived issue:

http://wikisend.com/download/144826/VfsTest2.java

Andreas